# What is an adjective that emphasises that a news story hasn't been diluted?

Tags: single-word-requests

Stories in media are often "watered-down or diluted". At the opposite extreme, they are sometimes sensationalised to make them appear more graphic than what really happened.

I'm looking for a term that indicates that the story *wasn't* diluted, but I'm not looking for the other extreme either.

What I'd like to express is that the reporting hasn't been edited, nor have elements been removed, to make it 'suitable for viewing by more people'. The news was relayed just as it happened.

Sample sentence:

> He read a lot of [not watered-down] stories.

Comment: Google `antonym dilute`

Comment: Other possibilities include ***comprehensive***, ***detailed***, and ***thorough***.  This is somewhat jargonny, but I believe that I’ve heard news people on television use the phrase ***extended** coverage* to refer to a comprehensive, in-depth version of a news story.

Comment: @MaxMaz I've edited your question for clarity. I don't think you were looking for generic antonyms of *dilute* (or synonyms of *concentrated*). Have a look at the changes, and if they don't express your intent, please feel free to [edit] further or to roll it back. Since the question was put on hold for lack of research, you should also [edit] the question to add some definitions and other relevant background, including words that you have considered, and why they don't convey the sense you intend. Questions on hold may be reopened once the issues identified have been addressed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**Unexpurgated**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/unexpurgated) would seem to fit the bill.

> adjective
>   1.
>   (of a book, text, etc) not amended or censored by removing potentially offensive material

He read a lot of ***unexpurgated*** stories.

Answer (score 0):

*He read (or viewed) a lot of **investigative reporting*** OR *He read (or viewed) a lot of **in-depth reporting***.

> [**Investigative
>   journalism**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Investigative_journalism) is
>   a form of journalism in which reporters deeply investigate a single
>   topic of interest, such as serious crimes, political corruption, or
>   corporate wrongdoing. An investigative journalist may spend months or
>   years researching and preparing a report. Investigative journalism is
>   a primary source of information.
>
> [**In-depth**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/in-depth): carefully
>   worked out, detailed and thorough

Answer (score 0):

You’re using a somewhat marginal and metaphoric meaning of *dilute*,
so it might be difficult to find antonyms with conventional searches. 
Here are some suggestions:

> ***comprehensive***:
>
> [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/comprehensive):
>
>     including many, most, or all things
>
> [Macmillan Dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/comprehensive):
>
>     including many details or aspects of something
>     - *We offer a comprehensive range of goods and services.*
>     - *a comprehensive guide to university courses*
>     - *a comprehensive policy review*
>
> [Cambridge English Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/comprehensive):
>
>     including everything that is necessary; complete:
>     *They put forward comprehensive legislation
>       to revise the rules for financing political campaigns.*
>
> ***in-depth***:
>
> [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/in-depth):
>
>     covering many or all important points of a subject
>
> [the Cambridge English Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/in-depth):
>
>     done carefully and in great detail:
>     *an in-depth report/interview/analysis*
>
> [Oxford dictionary (American English)](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/in-depth):
>
>     In great detail; comprehensively and thoroughly:
>     *‘ research students pursue a specific aspect
>       of a subject in depth’*

If you’ve heard or seen a story that was watered-down
and/or has had elements removed, you might seek to hear or see
the original, ***unabridged*** version.

> ***unabridged***:
>
> [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unabridged):
>
>     not shortened by leaving out some parts : not abridged

Similar words include ***detailed*** and ***thorough***. 
This is somewhat jargonny,
but I believe that I’ve heard news people on television
use the phrase ***extended*** coverage
to refer to a comprehensive, in-depth version of a news story.